# How to find files containing keywords from a list (search 2 million files for 60K keywords)?

Tags: shell, unix, search, grep

I have 2 million text files in a folder (actually subfolders, but lets simplify for explanation).
I have 60K URLs in a CSV file.
I would like to find all text files that contain one of the URLs found in the CSV file.

I tried the following step by step, but got an error:

```
# Get all the URLs in column 2 from data.csv and put in a variable
keywords=$(cut -d ',' -f 2 data.csv | tr '\n' '|')
# Search them with grep and find
find ./ -type f -exec grep -E -l "$keywords" {} \;
# Error as follows:
zsh: argument list too long: find
```

Do you know a clever way to achieve this in this scale?
Many thanks!

**UPDATE**
Improved version according to the suggestion (but it is very slow):

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -Flf data.txt '{}' +
```

with this data.txt

```
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1002064
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q101437
http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1020106
...
```

Comment: Step one: get a file with just the urls, one per line. Then try `find ./ -type f -exec grep -Flf urls.txt '{}' +`

Comment: Alternatively, look into [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/GUIDE.md), [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or similar tools.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you consider to store the files and keywords in database? This will simplify the work and probably speedup the process.

Comment: Regarding `grep -E` - do you REALLY want each URL to be used as a partial regexp comparison (so, for example, every `.` in it would match any character) instead of a full-line or other literal string comparison? If your URL is `http://example.com` and one of your files contains `http://example.company.net` should that be treated as a match? Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: @Shawn approach works for 1000 files to search, but it is terribly slow...so it's not practical.

Comment: @ Romeo Ninov Did not think about it, because the goal is relatively simple. I thought is could be done simply with a script without a database. But, if you have any concrete suggestions on your method with a simple use of a database, highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Untested given no sample input/output in the question but you probably want something like this (assuming no file names contain newlines):

```
find . -type f |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        while ( (getline url < "data.csv") > 0 ) {
            tgtUrls[url]
        }
    }
    NR == FNR {
        ARGV[ARGC++] = $0
        next
    }
    {
        for ( url in tgtUrls ) {
            line = $0
            while ( pos = index(line,url) ) {
                if ( substr(line,pos+length(url),1) !~ /[[:alnum:]_]/ ) {
                    print FILENAME
                    next
                }
                line = substr(line,pos+1)
            }
        }
    }
'
```

but you need to think about whether that string (`pos = index($0,url)`) + regexp (`substr($0,pos+length(url),1) !~ /[[:alnum:]_]/`) comparison combination is adequate to check if the URL really matches in the current line and isn't a substring of a longer URL, e.g. `http://example.com` falsely matching `http://example.company.net`, for your purposes and come up with some sample input/output that will test all of the rainy day cases you can have in your data where false matches are possible.

The above will take a while to run given the `index()` comparison will happen in the order of `60,000 URLs * 2 million files * the number of lines in each file` times.